# How can I display this information in a graph?

Tags: graphing-functions

within the context of a game, where x = damage, Spell = 0.7(x) + 60. I'm struggling to create a graph which would display the damage ratios. The x axis would be the damage, and the y axis would be the proportion of damage compared to the damage. So for example, when x = 50, y = (0.7x + 60)/x = 95/50 = 1.9. The Spell deals 90% more damage when the damage is 50. However when i put y=(0.7x + 60)/x into a graph maker, I don't get this result. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @TommyPersilPechey: Is this correct using [*WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B(.7+x+%2B+60)%2Fx,+%7Bx,+0,+100%7D%5D)?

Comment: I don't know how to respond to you or vote your answer as correct, but yes, that is exactly what I wanted. I don't know how I didn't get that with geogebra or whatever software I was using. Thank you!